# Em qual pasta devo adicionar os arquivos para serem lidos pelo Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python

Estou aprendendo a usar o Jupiter Notebook para estudar Análise de Dados, porém estou encontrando um problema em utilizá-lo. Na lição que estou fazendo, devemos ler alguns dados fornecidos com a extensão .csv. Contudo, ao rodar o programa para ler os arquivos, recebo a mensagem de que os módulos não foram encontrados. Imagino que não coloquei os arquivos no diretório correto, então gostaria de saber qual diretório deve ser utilizado de fato. Uso o PyCharm 3.7 e o Anaconda3.

[[image: 1]]

[[image: 2]]

Comment: Você tem que navegar ate a pasta. Provavelmente o jp notebook que vc abriu, foi aberto apontanto para uma pasta mais acima. Olha no canto superior de cima o caminho em que o seu arquivo está apontando. Por exemplo se ele estiver sendo aberto na pasta ANALISE seu comando tem que ser enrollments = read_csv(/venv library root/share/enrollments.csv). Obs: Quando for postar dúvida no stack, não coloque imagens do seu código e sim o código em si. Fica ruim para dar um ctrl+c + V para corrigir o mesmo, caso fosse necessário.

Comment: O path passado está correto? Acredito que você tenha que navegar até ele. Exemplo: read_csv(../enrollments.csv)

Comment: Eu achava que era algo automático, e que eu não deveria passar o caminho manualmente. Após a explicação de vocês consegui utilizar. Muito obrigada.

Comment: Marcos, é a primeira vez que uso o Stack para tirar dúvidas, obrigada pela dica!

Answer (score 1):

Cria um arquivo .bat com a inicialização do jupyter notebook na pasta onde está este arquivo enrollment.csv

- Na pasta do arquivlo enrollment.csv cria um arquivo .txt e escreva nele jupyter notebook
- Salve o arquivo .txt
- Altere a extensão do arquivo acima para .bat e salve
- Execute o arquivo

Essa sequencia de operações vai abrir o jupyter notebook direto na pasta do arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Andressa, recomendo-te a fazer o seguinte. Na pasta onde você está a utilizar o notebook criado, na aba de endereços da pasta digite `jupyter notebook`. Seu sistema abrirá uma janela de inicialização do processo do Jupyter Notebook e abrirá em vosso navegador principal a pasta em que ele está.
Caso tenha algum conhecimento de manipulação de arquivos HTML, você poderá utilizar uma navegação local para atingir tais arquivos. Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se você estiver no `arquivo_2_1` e quiser acessar informações do `arquivo_1_2`, terá que fazer o caminho `'../arquivo_1/arquivo_1_2`.